# Find out number of commits given two commit hashes

Tags: mercurial

In a mercurial repository, how can I count the number of commits between two hashes?

For example, if the tree is like

```
A
|
B
|
C
|
D
|
E
|
F
```

How can I find out the number of commits between A and F? In this example, it would be 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this to list all the commits:

```
hg log --rev "1500::1550" --template "{rev} "
```

then pipe it to a word count tool.

```
hg log --rev "1500::1550" --template "{rev} " | wc
```

one could use "`children(1500)::p1(1550)`" to only get the inner changesets, but it's safer to just subtract `2` from the final result. That way one doesn't have to care about end changeset having multiple parents.

Updated based on comment.

Comment: Or, shorter, use the revset syntax `x::y`. Remember to subtract two from the count, as this includes both endpoints.